# Mongo db connection is not establishing

Tags: mongodb, express

// mongo.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = require('./router');
    const mongoConnection = require('./mongo')
    const cors = require('cors');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    
    const api = express();
    const port = 3000;
    
    api.listen(port, ()=>{
        console.log('port is running successfully');
    });
    api.use(cors())
    
    api.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    api.use(bodyParser.json())
    
    api.use(express.json());
    api.use('/api', router);
    
    mongoConnection();
```

// index.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
    const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
    const mongoUrl = process.env.DB_URL;`


const mongoConnection = async () => {
    try {
        const dbConnection = await mongoose.connect(mongoUrl);
        console.log("DB is connected", dbConnection);
    } catch {
        
    } finally {
        await mongoose.disconnect();
    }
}

module.exports = mongoConnection;
```

Hi Team, I've hard time connecting my DB is here. Earlier It was doing fine and showing "port running successfully" and "Db is connected". Now Db connection is not establishing and can't see the error also.

I tried, Sudo mongod also and not working. Any leads would help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the connection string? Is the database running at that location? What error are you getting?

Comment: @user20042973, you mean, DB_URL = mongodb://localhost:27017/admin ???
I cant see the error, I cant see it is running at anyplace.

Comment: _"`Sudo mongod` also and not working"_  What's the error message?  What errors and warnings are in `mongod.log`?

Comment: Sounds like your local instance of mongodb isn't running correctly and it's not an issue with the code/javascript. If the usual command you use to start the db (`sudo mongod`) isn't working then it may be worth just restarting your computer and trying again as something may be running in the background causing the issue.

Comment: Print the error in the `catch` block.